# BottomNavigation view ripple color effect

Tags: android, user-interface, bottomnavigationview

I've seen this ripple color effect on Material Calculator app, on the Google Play and now on the BottomNavigation view.

How can I make this color effect starting from touch?

Gif: https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/72535/screenshots/2673294/bottom_navigation_material_design_by_jardson_almeida.gif

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think it will be easier if you use style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/ripple_material_dark</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks. This actually does the magic. Also I found a library which simplifies the work :)

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to make simple ripple, then here is code to change color of it:

```
RippleDrawable rippleDrawable = (RippleDrawable)view.getBackground(); // assumes bg is a RippleDrawable

int[][] states = new int[][] { new int[] { android.R.attr.state_enabled} };
int[] colors = new int[] { Color.BLUE }; // sets the ripple color to blue

ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
rippleDrawable.setColor(colorStateList);
```

Comment: thank you, I didn't know about this, I'll study this. I found a library on Github which does the effect with one line in the xml. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers do the work but I found a library which simplifies the work when using BottomNavigation:

https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar